# Specify milliseconds in JBoss 7 access log

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j

I've enabled the access log on my JBoss 7 installation like this:

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
   <alias name="localhost"/>
   <alias name="example.com"/>
   <access-log pattern="&quot;%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b %{User-Agent}i %{JSESSIONID}c&quot;">
      <directory path="access"/>
   </access-log>
</virtual-server>
```

An example of a log message that is getting written is:

> 72.109.104.175 - - [27/Dec/2013:07:59:25 -0500] "POST /axis2/services/FooService HTTP/1.1" 200 652 Axis2 -"

This is showing the date time of the log message down to the second.

How can I change the log pattern so that the milliseconds are included in the timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can specify the time taken in milliseconds using **%D** in the access log pattern
2. tomcat allows you to specify the date and time using SimpleDateFormat and you might be able to specify time in millseconds but this will be the number of milliseconds since epoch. Earlier version of jboss were bundled with tomcat but I dont think jboss 7 does not comes with tomcat so you will need to check whether this is supported in jboss 7.

Reference : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html